# Docker build hangs during downloads

Tags: java, macos, docker

Mac 10.10.5 here, using `docker-machine` to create a VirtualBox host VM for my local Docker. I have a project that builds an executable JVM located at `build/libs/myapp-SNAPSHOT.jar`. My `Dockerfile`, which is located in the root of the project, looks like:

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim
VOLUME /tmp
ADD build/libs/myapp-SNAPSHOT.jar myapp.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /myapp.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/myapp.jar"]
```

Please note, I don't wish to *push* my images to any registry, just keep/run them locally (for now). When I run:

```
docker build -t myorg/myapp .
```

I get the following console output:

```
myuser@mymachine:~/sandbox/myapp$docker build -t myorg/myapp .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 42.69 MB
Step 1 : FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim
slim: Pulling from frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8

d0ca440e8637: Downloading [=================================================> ] 2.295 MB/2.32 MB
0f86278f6be1: Downloading [=================================================> ] 3.149 MB/3.172 MB
c704a6161dca: Download complete
```

And then the command-line just hangs after printing that "*Download complete*" message. I've waited for as long as 30 minutes (!!!) and nothing happens.

Any ideas where I'm going awry?

Comment: Why the downvote sans explanation? This is *not* a dupe, shows research, is an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and is **totally** on topic (if `Dockerfile` questions are off topic for SO, my name is Alan Greenspan).

Comment: Sounds like you have an issue with the virtual machine initializing. First thing I would do is restart and try again. If that does't work, try re-installing docker. If that fails,  try on a Linux or Windows host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VM is probably hanging. Try the following: https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/1819#issuecomment-138981139

```
docker-machine rm -f default
rm -fv ~/.docker/machine
docker-machine -D create -d virtualbox default
```

[There are more issues about this on OSX.](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/986)

I think the best practice is to setup a Linux native build box if you are doing any serious development. That way you can run docker without any VM overhead(which is ironically one of the major pain points docker is trying to solve)

There's also a [Docker Beta program](https://beta.docker.com/) which runs on libcontainer natively on OSX and Windows.

Comment: Thanks @Stanislav Palatnik (+1), I tried your suggestions but none of them worked. I'd be interested in "Docker for Mac 1.0" but not some Beta version that may or may not be wonky. I'm going to switch to a Linux machine for my Docker dev until Mac/Docker can make a beautiful baby together...and when time has proven that this beautiful baby is battle tested and not a beta baby :-)